# Multilang Bug with Matrix, Neo, SuperTable (with Video)

Tags: matrix, localization, plugin-supertable, plugin-neo

We have a big problem with CraftCMS and Multilang.

1. We have the default language German (DE) in Craft.
2. We have news entries with matrix fields
3. We create a new language English (EN) as second language
4. We activate this language (EN) in the News section
5. We open an existing news entry and click on the second language (EN)
6. The content of the matrix field does not exist
7. We go WITHOUT saving back to the source language (DE) and save the post
8. We switch back to the second language (EN) and now the Matrix Content is here

For us it seems that the Autosave function, which is triggered when you add a new language to a section, does not process the matrix fields (Neo + SuperTable same problem) properly.

The Problem is on all our client sites which use multilang.

Here is a Video
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jzg6ts3l90xze1/craftbug.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially running into this bug: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/16

It has been fixed for the upcoming Craft 3, but the fix was involved likely won't be backported to Craft 2.

Comment: The problem is we've a Craft Multilang Commerce Project in the Pipeline. That means we can do that in C2 with this (huge) bug or we can wait until C3 + CC is ready :/ hm